# Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

While loading my Kibana dashboard, It just stuck at loading window. When I go and check the problem via "Developer Tools". I found the below error, Someone please help me to fix this.

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: kibana

Some forum advised to increase the require.js file waitSeconds value. But no luck.

Someone please help me on this to fix[image]

Comment: Please post the errors as text in you question - not in a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by changing the timeout value in require.js file. I think, the problem script got timed out because of my link Bandwidth.

Thanks